# 'ridurre ad un terzo' e 'ridurre ad un quarto'

Tags: idioms, verbs, word-meaning

Si sente spesso parlare degli spropositati redditi dei dirigenti della pubblica amministrazione, normalmente superiori a 150.000,00 €/anno; e si auspica siano 'dimezzati'.

Ci sono poi moltissimi casi in cui tali redditi sono finanche superiori, e di molto, a 200.000,00 €/anno e, conseguentemente, andrebbero ridotti ad un terzo o ad un quarto.

Così come 'dimezzare' significa 'ridurre ad un mezzo', ci sono singole parole che significano 'ridurre ad un terzo' e 'ridurre ad un quarto'?

Answer (score 5):

Visto che la domanda è taggata [idioms](/questions/tagged/idioms), mi urge sottolineare che nè "rinquartare", "inquartare", "interzare", "squartare" o "sterzare" sono idiomi in uso comune. Risulta molto più naturale "ridurre a un terzo" — o meglio ancora, "ridurre *di* due terzi," "ridurre *del* 75%."

Si potrebbe inventare una spiegazione per questa mia impressione da speaker nativo: nell'espressione "ridurre dell'*x* percento", *x* è la quantità di riduzione; sembra dunque più logico, o quantomeno più diretto, di "ridurre al (100−*x*)%." Probabilmente però la mia preferenza ha semplicemente radici nell'uso tipico che si fa di queste espressioni nei telegiornali e nelle trasmissioni televisive di natura politica, in cui spesso le variazioni in ballo sono frazioni di punto percentuale. Confronta:

- "Il PIL nel Gennaio 2025 si è ridotto al 99.2% rispetto al suo valore nello stesso mese del 2024."* [Messaggio implicito: niente panico! va tutto bene! non c'è crisi! è quasi 100!]
- "Il PIL nel Gennaio 2025 si è ridotto dello 0.8% al suo valore nello stesso mese del 2024."* [Messaggio implicito: allarme! siamo in piena recessione!]

Le mie riserve sull'uso di "ridurre a" diventano al contrario raccomandazioni nei casi in cui il nuovo valore venga specificato in termini assoluti:

- "Prendevo 1,500€ di stipendio, ma con le nuove tasse il mio salario si è ridotto a 1,350€."
  [Messaggio implicito: e io con 1,350€ come arrivo alla fine del mese?]
- "Prendevo 1,500€ di stipendio, ma con le nuove tasse il mio salario si è ridotto di 150€."
  [Probabilmente il messaggio implicito è lo stesso, ma qui io mi distraggo a calcolare quanto prendi ora...]

Answer (score 4):

Per "dividere in quarti" esiste "[squartare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/squartare/)", che però, come puoi leggere nella definizione stessa, è generalmente legato al macello di una bestia o a un'esecuzione capitale, inoltre il significato si limita al "dividere", manca quindi il senso proprio di riduzione; ciò non toglie che letteralmente corrisponda a "dividere in quattro parti".

Invece per quanto riguarda "ridurre a un terzo", ciò che ho trovato di più simile è, anche se non più in uso in questa accezione, [sterzare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sterzare1/).

Comment: Anedoctal, but “smezzare” seems to be still used, at least locally.

Answer (score 2):

[*Rinquartare*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rinquartare/) ha tra i suoi significati “dividere per quattro”, ma visto che può significare anche “moltiplicare per quattro” non lo consiglierei; [*inquartare*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/inquartare/) e [*interzare*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/interzare/) hanno anche i significati di dividere per quattro e per tre (oltre ad altri che interferiscono, come sopra), ma sono usati quasi solo in araldica